# Connect my form to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I was trying to connect a form to my but can't seem to make it work. Any help, please?

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="info.php" method="post">
         <label for"email">Vaša e-mail adresa</label>
         <input type="email" name="EMAIL" required>
         <textarea name="recenzija" class="recenzija" rows="10" columns:"1" name="TEKST" required>Otkucajte ili kopirajte vaš tekst ovde (do oko 400 reči).</textarea>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji">
        </form
```

And the PHP

```
<?php
$servername = "mysql";
$username = "podkupol_filmski";
$password = "123";
$dbname = "podkupol_konkurs";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($mysql, $podkupol_filmski, $123, $podkupol_konkurs);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO konkurs (EMAIL, TEKST)
VALUES ('EMAIL', 'TEKST')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Hvala!";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I keep getting this message:

> Connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

Comment: Try changing `$servername = "mysql";` to `$servername = "localhost";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$conn = new mysqli($mysql, $podkupol_filmski, $123, $podkupol_konkurs);
```

should be either your variables or strings, you are setting variables which you don't use but pass unset variables in you connection string.

try it like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

SIDENOTE:

As @developerwjk has mentioned in his comment, 'mysql' should be changed to localhost, or the actual hosts ip address.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! It did work, but the host name needed to remain "mysql", because this is how my server defines it.